# Computing the Supremum of a Family

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to compute (or bound) the supremum $\sup_{n\in \mathbf{Z}} n^p x^n$ for fixed $p<2\in \mathbf{R}$. It should be noted that $x\in [0,1]$. My professor suggested that I bound this by 
$$ \sup_{n\in \mathbf{N}}n^px^n\le \sup_{t\in \mathbf{R}} t^px^t.$$
From here, I am trying to compute a bound for the supremum over real numbers $t$. It looks like this can be achieved using some calculus trickery. Namely, set $f(t)=t^pe^{(\ln x) \cdot t}$. Then, we have that 
$$ f'(t)=pt^{p-1}e^{(\ln x)\cdot t}+t^p \ln xe^{(\ln x)\cdot t}=x^tt^{p-1}(p+t\ln x).$$
Setting this derivative to $0$, we have that 
$$ x^t t^{p-1}(p+t\ln x)=0.$$
Now, either $t=0$, $x=0$, or $(p+t\ln x)=0$. Clearly the $t=0$ case is not a maximum, and the $x=0$ case is trivial because for $x$, the family has value $0$ for all $t$. So, the only other zero I can find is 
$$ t=\frac{-p}{\ln x}.$$
I'm not exactly sure what to do with this information. If anyone could give me a hint or suggestion, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are we to treat $x$ as fixed?

Comment: Well, that's a good question. In my calculation, I did treat $x$ as fixed. Perhaps that isn't the way to go, though. Ultimately, I'm trying to show that a certain integral is finite, which suggests that I need to find a uniform bound in both $t$ and $x$. The integral is 

$\int_{[0,1]} \sup_n f_nd\mu(x)$, for $f_n=n^px^n(1-x)$.

Comment: It is. $x$ is fixed: for fixed $p$ and $x\in(0,1)$ (you have no control over them; for $x=0$ or $x=1$, the answer to your original question is immediate), you want to maximize $t^p x^t$ with regard to $t$. So here, you found that the derivative cancelled for a particular value of $t^\ast$ (function of $x$ and $p$): it's either a (local) maximum, a (local) mininum, or nothing particular. You could either campute the second derivate of $f$ to check $f''(t^\ast)$, or first look at $f(t^\ast)$ along with the sign of $f'$ for $t>t^\ast$ and $t<t^\ast$, to conclude.

Comment: That's true, but my main concern is that $t=-p/\ln x$ appears to behave terribly if I range $x\in (0,1)$.

Comment: I don't see any reason for this not to blow up for $t \to -\infty$ (and $x$ tiny).

Comment: The idea of your professor is that you have $$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} n^p x^n \leq \sup_{r\in\mathbb{R}} t^p x^t$$ (can you see why?), but computing the right one is usually **much** simpler (since you can use calculus, real analysis, you name it; optimizing functions over a discrete domain is **much** tricker). Then, the hope is that the bound given by the right supremum is not too lose with regard to the original, left one (and "usually" it is not)

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis $x$ is fixed. Think of it as a constant. Write $x_0$ is that helps -- right now, you only want the supremum **with regard to $t$**.

Comment: (Although, are you sure that the original question was not for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ instead of $n\in\mathbb{Z}$? To address @Mr.Chip's concern, because then you can restrict $t$ to be non-negative)

Comment: Amusingly enough, it wasn't specified - the parameter was simply labeled as $n$. At first I was treating it as though it was natural, perhaps that is the correct approach.

Comment: Yes, with quite high probability... In that case, the "relaxation" would be $n\in\mathbb{N} \leadsto t\in[0,\infty)$, and what you have found will indeed lead to a maximum:$$f(t^\ast) = \left(\frac{p}{\ln(1/x)}\right)^px^{-\frac{p}{\ln x}}
= \left(\frac{p}{\ln(1/x)}\right)^p e^{-p}
= \left(\frac{p}{e\ln(1/x)}\right)^p
$$

Comment: Clement C. what if $p < 0$, so $t^* < 0$?

Comment: Consider the example $p = -2, x = 0.5$. Then you're looking at $t^{-2} \cdot 0.5^t$, which has an infinite supremum for $t \ge 0$. To solve the problem, the OP should probably treat $p < 0$ and $p \ge 0$ separately; the former situation can be done directly if you just want to bound the original supremum.

Comment: @Mr.Chip My guess is that came into some result about power series, and $0\leq p\leq 2$. That's for the OP to clarify though. But in any case, what you mention above is again easily fixable, since you can even consider $t\in[1,\infty)$ only (relaxation from natural numbers...)

Comment: Again, I would clarify if I could. The problems statement simply states "for which $p$ does this hold." This question here is more in regards to a technicality necessary for solving a certain case. It is worth mentioning that I have managed to eliminate all cases but the $1<p<2$ case. I was, however, hoping for a method which would address all cases simultaneously.

Comment: Well, the above does, if you deal with $n$ non-zero natural integers (since then the relaxation can be $t\in[1,\infty)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $n$ is natural, according to one of your comments. If $p \le 0$, you can bound $n^p x^n \le x^n \le 1$ and don't even need to pass to the real variable $t$. Therefore let's say $p > 0$.

Assume $p$ and $0 < x < 1$ are fixed; the boundary cases for $x$ are trivial. It suffices for your original purpose to take $t \ge 0$.

Notice that the sign of $f'(t)$ is dictated by the term $p + t \ln x$, which is linear in $t$. It therefore switches sign exactly once, from positive to negative (since $\ln x < 0$), at $t = t_0 = -p/\ln x > 0$, as you stated. Hence your supremum is
$$f(t_0) = \left ( \frac{-p}{e \ln x} \right )^p.$$